# Why when I cat the node directory in `/usr/local/bin` does it unleash cthulhu?

Tags: node.js, cat

So I was installing node and somehow I ended up in the `/user/local/bin` folder checking what was there.

I wanted to so a `ls | grep node` but did a `ls | cat node`. The node directory then started to show itself in all its glory. I chuckled, laughed, then stopped the `cat` but that left my terminal looking something like this:

[image]

It is easily fixable by exiting the window.

I don't recommend you try it but i've managed to recreate it reliably. Just cat the node directory leave it for a few seconds then cancel it.

My question is what on earth is going on here? AFAIK using `cat` shouldn't be able to make this stuff happen.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/why-using-cat-on-binary-files-messed-up-the-terminal-and-how

Answer (score 2):

Terminals interpret [certain combinations of bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) as commands. This is how command line programs can output colors, or change the cursor position. What you're seeing is the output after one of these commands activated a box drawing character set by accident. You can activate it yourself with `echo` or `printf`:

```
my cool prompt$ printf '\033(0'
└≤ ␌⎺⎺┌ ⎻⎼⎺└⎻├$
```

To get out of this mess, type `reset` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - it will clear the screen and set all settings back to default.

```
└≤ ␌⎺⎺┌ ⎻⎼⎺└⎻├$ ⎼␊⎽␊├

(..screen clears..)

my cool prompt$
```

Answer (score 1):

You managed to output the contents of the `node` executable to the terminal. What happens when you output random octets to the terminal depends on what those characters are and on the terminal. It often leaves the terminal in a state that the user did not really expect.